# USB-LAN adapter over USB hub

Tags: raspbian, networking, usb, ethernet-port

I want to make a router-access point with a Raspberry PI model B.
But I need 5 LAN ports (4 WAN ports and 1 LAN).

So I tried this:

- On one USB I place an [USB Hub](https://www.modmypi.com/New-Link-4-Port-USB-Hub-%28USB-2.0-with-Mains-Adaptor%29?filter_tag=USB%20Hub)
- and on every port a [usb-lan adapter](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/410BKvA4IxL._SX385_.jpg)

Can Debian read 4 LAN's over `USB hub-->USB-LAN` adapter?

Comment: Why don't you use a simple [network hub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_hub) or switch? I don't think you can power so many usb-lan adapters.

Comment: I think he wants to connect 4 WAN and share it to his local network for load balancing. The hint is `(4 WAN and 1 LAN)` A standard switch will also work with VLANS or simple IP masking but I think the OP has no idea about networking. I suggest to use a router like MicroTik or pfSense for this with Gigabit ports and software that knows how to handle load balancing.

Comment: Remember that the maximum bandwidth will be 480mbits for both send and receive on the entire USB hub on the Pi. That is technically megabytes total bandwidth at any time the Pi can handle on USB. So if you start to copy data of a USB hard drive over 1Gbit you will fully saturate the USB - So make sure not to connect high speed devices to the Pi if you need to load balance 4 WAN's or you will get speed issues at maximum load.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reasonw why it wouldn't work.
Debian can read as many devices as you have plugged in.
Your bandwidth will be shocking though as all devices will be sharing the same bus, and thus bandwidth. CPU usage will also be very high due to the inefficient USB stack that the Pi uses.

This is all assuming that the USB LAN adapters you have don't have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can; you'll need a powered USB hub though, to power up all these adapters, and you'll have a hard time achieving 100mbit throughput. USB 2.0 is 480 Mbit/s half-duplex, over one cable between RPi and the hub, no matter what communicates with what, e.g. transmission between two local ports.

Enumerating and addressing all these devices in Linux before setting up routing will be a drudgery too. Doable, but IMHO not worth the effort.

Personally, I believe you'd be far better off using *one* USB-Ethernet adapter, turning RPi into a router with 1 WAN and 1 LAN port, and one dumb network switch for creating the remaining 4 LAN ports. That way you get 100mbit throughput to WAN and save up on 3 USB adapters.

Still, this all is an interesting but not very useful exercise. Getting a dedicated router where you can replace the firmware with your own will be more fault-proof, easier, and cheaper.